# Git Moving a Branch to Another One with One Commit History

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-merge

I'm developing at my feature branch. After the development completed, i will move all committed code to master branch.

But specificated point is after this operation master branch should have only one commit history.

I will try to explain with trees.

```
--- BRANCH TREES WITHOUT MERGE OPERATION ---

A--B--C  (master-branch)
 \    ^--- After the merge operation commit will come after this point.
  \
   D--E--F--G  (feature-branch)


--- AFTER THE MERGE OPERATION EXPECTED BRANCH TREES ---

A--B--C--(H)  (master-branch)
 \        ^--- 'H' is the commit of all feature branch merge. 
  \             Include commits D, E, F, G.  
   \            This should have all source but, will shown one commit   message.
    \
     D--E--F--G  (feature-branch)
```

How can i merge these branches like this?

Comment: moving to master means merging into master branch

Comment: @PankajBadukale This doesn't meant only for master branch. It can be another feature branch too.

Comment: Do you want `feature-branch` origin (commit `A`) to be changed. If yes do a squash commit when rebasing process. If no the merge of `feature-branch` into `master` will result into one merge commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git calls this a "squash merge", and you obtain it by running `git merge --squash`.  As with all new commits in Git, the new commit will be added to the current branch, so in this case you would get on `master-branch` first, then run `git merge --squash feature-branch`.

#### Caveats

There are some important things to know about this.  In particular, while the *tree* (source or work tree) associated with the resulting commit is obtained by *merging* (the verb: the action, "to merge"), it is not a *merge commit* (adjective or noun form of merge).

Remember that in Git, commits have two functions:

- They *are* the history.
- They *contain* work-tree snapshots (plus some metadata: who made the commit, and when, and a log message).

A normal `git merge other` finds a *merge base* commit by running `git merge-base --all HEAD other`,<sup>1</sup> then:

- Combines two sets of diffs: diffs from the base to `HEAD`, which amount to "what you changed", plus diffs from the base to `other`, which amount to "what they changed".  If you changed file `one.txt` and they changed file `two.txt`, Git takes both changes, i.e., your `one.txt` and their `two.txt`.  If you *both* changed file `three.txt`, Git tries to see whether your changes and theirs overlap, or are exact duplicates, or are entirely independent.  If they overlap, Git gives you a merge conflict.  If they are independent, Git takes both changes.  If they are exact duplicates, Git takes one copy of the change.  The resulting `three.txt` is the output of a *three-way merge*.
- Makes a new commit whose *history* says: "this commit is a merge commit, combining the work from the first parent `HEAD` and the second parent `other`".

A `git merge --squash` other still does the merge action, including any required three-way merges.  It then—for no obvious reason<sup>2</sup>—omits the `git commit` step and makes you run `git commit`, and when you *do* run `git commit`, the result is *not* a merge commit: its history says "this commit is an ordinary commit, and its sole parent is `HEAD`".  Its commit history is, in other words, as if you had made all of the changes from `other`, except for any duplicated ones, by yourself.

This is what you are asking for, but it is also something of a trap.  Should you decide, at a later time, that you need to develop more on `feature-branch` and merge again, Git won't have the history that shows an existing merge, and won't know that it could start the new merge process using the previous merge's result.

What this means in the end is that squash merges work best when you intend to *delete* the feature branch immediately (or at least very soon) after squash-merging:

```
A---B----C      <-- main
 \
  D--E--F--G    <-- feature
```

(now `git checkout main && git merge --squash feature && git commit && git branch -D feature`)

```
A---B----C--H   <-- main
 \
  D--E--F--G    [abandoned]
```

That way, you cannot go back and add more commits past `G` that use the `D-E-F-G` chain that later require merging again.  If you did go back and make such commits, and merge again, the merge base commit would be `A`, not `G`, and Git would be more likely to mis-merge, accidentally duplicating some of the `D-E-F-G` changes.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>If `git merge-base --all` finds more than one merge base, the behavior depends on the merge *strategy*.  If it finds *no* merge base, the behavior in old versions of Git and new versions of Git differs: newer Gits stop with an error about refusing to merge unrelated histories.

<sup>2</sup>A regular merge will *also* stop, but only if specifically requested with `--no-commit`.  A subsequent `git commit` will make a merge commit, i.e., a two-parent commit.  So there's no reason for `git merge --squash` to act as if you also specified `--no-commit`: if you *really wanted* it to stop, you could run `git merge --squash --no-commit`.  (It's likely that this is a holdover from the earliest Git scripts.)

<sup>3</sup>Git's merge algorithm, which tries hard to take just one copy of each change, will often succeed at taking just one copy of the change.  That is, the diff from `A` to whatever comes after `G` includes all the `D-E-F-G` changes, and the diff from `A` to whatever comes at or after `H` *also* includes all the `D-E-F-G` changes: but that's what "take one copy of the changes" is *meant* to handle.

The problem is that when you stress this algorithm too hard, it fails.  Usually, the effect is a gigantic merge conflict that you must resolve by hand.

Comment: Really thanks for detailed answer :) That is what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is, the 'squash commits' feature.

I'd just make a copy of the original branch, and then rebase it interactively, so I can squash the commits.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches:

```
git checkout -b tmp feature-branch
git reset A --soft
git commit -m "feature"
#a new commit X is created. It's a squash of D, E, F, G
git checkout master-branch
git cherry-pick X
git branch -D tmp
```